# WIN32 IsClipboardFormatAvailable function does not set last error code

Tags: c, winapi

In documentation

> If the clipboard format is not available, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
> [IsClipboardFormatAvailable function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isclipboardformatavailable)

but the output of this code is 0:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <winerror.h>
int main()
{
    //I copied an image to the clipboard before running the program
    if(!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT))
    {

        printf("%lu", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

Why didn't the IsClipboardFormatAvailable function set the last error?

Comment: simply documentation is wrong. or implementation is wrong. `IsClipboardFormatAvailable` not set last error on fail. as is

Comment: My *guess* is that `IsClipboardFormatAvailable` is correctly setting the error code to 0 because it successfully judged that the format is not available in the clipboard. One way to test this hypothesis is calling another API that set the last error to non-zero value before calling `IsClipboardFormatAvailable ` and see if the value changes to 0.

Comment: What additional information would you expect? "Yep, checked again, still not there, sorry."

Comment: @MikeCAT- no, wrong guess. `NtUserIsClipboardFormatAvailable` first call `CheckClipboardAccess` and this call **set** last error on fail. then compare thread desktop with `grpdeskLogon` (*Winlogon*) and if equal - return FALSE and **not set** any last error. finally call *FindClipFormat* and again, if not found - **not set** any last error. despite must set `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` or something like this

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isclipboardformatavailable) says *If the clipboard format is available, the return value is nonzero. If the clipboard format is not available, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.* But there isn't an error situation: it's just reporting the clipboard status. The doc seems to need an edit anyway, because it should return `true` or `false` not 'nonzero or zero' (although they are effectively the same thing).

Comment: @WeatherVane - *But there isn't an error situation* - this is 100% error situation , if required element ( clipboard format in concrete case) not found ( not available )

Comment: @RbMm there was no error in the operation of the function call, which simply reports as asked. An error would be failing to obtain the clipboard status.

Comment: @WeatherVane no, this is 100% error here

Comment: Try passing a null pointer to the function (and duck and expect errors), but maybe that will trigger a GetLastError() non-zero return. I wouldn't expect an GetLastError() non-zero return for a simple call that the format isn't there.

Comment: @RbMm why is it an error if the clipboard had copied plain text with format `CF_OEMTEXT`, and so it doesn't hold information of the desired format, say `CF_PALETTE`, and this function correctly reports that state?

Comment: @WeatherVane if you ask some element ant it not exist - this is error - not found. the same is for files, registry keys, other objects. format not found. this is error by windows conventional and error code must say about reason

Comment: No, the function's return value tells you that. That is what the function is for. The error status is for when the function cannot do what it is expected to do.

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, you absolute wrong. return value nothing tell about error reason. try open not existing file. it is not error based on what you say. simply file not exist. but you wrong . this is error

Comment: @RbMm either the clipboard holds information of the requested format, or it does not. If it does not, that is not an error but a statement of fact.

Comment: @WeatherVane - absolute nonce. if you ask open file and file not exist - this is also not error ? yes ? :)) simply fact - file not exist ))

Comment: This is not a file.

Comment: @WeatherVane - and so what ?

Comment: Because this question is about the clipboard.

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, because you look like bad know windows internals. there are general principles. and are the same for all objects. If we request an object (or its existence) and the system cannot return it to us, this is an error. the reasons may be different - the absence of an object, no access rights, sharing violation. etc. all this is errors and error code must explain reason

Comment: OTOH `OpenClipboard()` can fail and set the error status. But here, if the function succeeds in informing the caller of the clipboard status, that is not an error. Which is what OP has found.

Comment: @WeatherVane - what you say only show your bad knowledge on windows, nothing more. absolute noncence

Comment: Please don't make personal attacks but cite your source.

Comment: @WeatherVane you say obviously wrong technical things

Comment: Then please post an answer to the OP's question "Why didn't the IsClipboardFormatAvailable function set the last error?"

Comment: How could there be an error reason that tells the caller more than the function's return value "the clipboard does not contain this format"?

Comment: @WeatherVane can be any other error reason. for instance - we on Winlogon desktop. will be error even if clipboard containing requested format

Comment: I think you are demonstrating my case now. Not having the requested format isn't itself an error. Go on – write your answer showing why the OS should have flagged an error in the OP's example.

Comment: @WeatherVane no, this is 100% error of couse and not show any "your case". for write answer i need time. but i will do this

Comment: So, **why was there no error reported**?

Comment: @WeatherVane - because this is error in implementation

Comment: Are you saying the OP's code has a bug, or the Windows code has a bug? Be careful, now.

Comment: @WeatherVane i say windows code have bug

Comment: Three options here: 1. the clipboard format is available, in that case return value is nonzero. 2. clipboard format is not available but no error happened - GetLastError returned zero. 3. clipboard format is not available due to some error (e.g. Access Denied) - GetLastError returned that error code.

Comment: @vasek - no, this not how windows work. here only 2 options. if clipboard format is not available - this is error. and error code must say reason of error

Comment: @RbMm then you should definitely write an answer explaining why there is a bug in the Windows code, and not in *your* understanding of the way this function works. I say the the error status would be set when a) the function failed to obtain the status, or b) the requested status is invalid.

Comment: @WeatherVane - i already say - i definitely will write an answer, but i need some time to do this

Comment: @RbMm to me GetLastError is something like exception. But if clipboard does not contain something, it's not really an exception, it's just normal state. Yes, if we could not get to the clipboard because of running in sandbox and whatnot, yes, that's exception for sure. But I don't really see this happening here.

Comment: @vasek - no, you are wrong. again - this no how windows work. this is not like exeption. if element not found - this is error. also possible requested format **exist** in clipboard, but function return 0 because thread on winlogon desktop. and last error anyway not set. so you can not know different - not exist format, or wrong desktop, or something else

Comment: @RbMm going from the way this sort of thing works on Windows, is that if you are expecting the format to be present in the clipboard data, and it isn't, then you would look at the error status to determine whether there was an error retrieving the status, or it really doesn't (for some other reason) contain the data you expect.

Comment: @RbMm instead of persisting in telling two other users that they are wrong, please move straight to writing an answer.

Comment: This isn't an "element not found" situation, you're not asking the function to give you the data. You're just asking it if the data is there. I'm sorry but I agree this is not an error.

Comment: @WeatherVane - i post answer

Comment: @JonathanPotter - no different. api must explain **why** element not found (or avaible). and reason can ve not only because element  not exist

Comment: I don't get why you think Windows would know that the format isn't present. What added value do you think it could give in an error status, when the function succeeded?

Comment: @JonathanPotter - see my answer and example with `PathFileExistsW` - *You're just asking it if the data is there.* (or file (file is data) ) is there. yes ? this is relevant example ? why in this case last error not 0 ?

Comment: @WeatherVane - see my answer and example with `PathFileExistsW` - You're just asking it if the data is there. (or file (file is data) ) is there. yes ? this is relevant example ? why in this case last error not 0

Comment: Seems an internal error. I will report it.

Comment: You can report it to Microsoft directly. Send feedback to us so that it will attract more attention. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this pattern before. Typically `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()` is not a function that can fail; and there's not expected to be anything useful to report because the last thing in the clipboard just doesn't match any known format.

If you're really in a situation where `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()` can fail and need to check and do something about the difference, this fragment is correct:

```
   SetLastError(0);
   if(!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT))
   {
       if (GetLastError() == 0)
       {
           printf("Clipboard doesn't contain text.");
       } else {
           printf("IsClipboardFormatAvailable: %lu", GetLastError());
       }
   }
```

You described a case of image in the clipboard in the question. The function didn't fail.

Comment: what if you run on winlogon ( `grpdeskLogon` ) desktop ? `IsClipboardFormatAvailable` return false **always** in this case. and not set any last error.

Comment: @RbMm: An exceedingly unlikely case that OP isn't going to get into by accident. In effect, the winlogon desktop has no clipboard so it's not even really wrong.

Comment: winlogon desktop have clipboard too. but begin from some windows version - exist check for this desktop and fail in this case. for instance `OpenClioboard` return error access denied in case winlogon desktop. but we say about generic patterns, not about concrete case. documentation for function say about this - error code **must** be set if false returned. and error code **must** explain real reason (not exist format, access denied, wrong desktop, etc)

Comment: @RbMm: There are a few other such functions on Windows in this class where you must explicitly do `SetLastError(0);` I've encountered the pattern a handful of times. Another function in this class is `GetTraceEnableFlags()`.

Comment: and so what ? here this is not related. at all discussion was - are error or not that object not exist. i say that this is error from windows view (this is how system design)

Comment: @RbMm: And how system design is GetClipboardFormat cannot fail and so is expected to preserve SetLastError across invocation and only years later on the NT branch did it ever get an actual failure mode and so they had to go back and add SetLastError on failure but due to compatibility they had to keep its ancient behavior of don't stomp SetLastError because the clipboard format is not what the caller expects.

Comment: documentation is clear here - *if the clipboard format is not available, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError* - must be set last error if function return false. and this error must explain reason. if reason - no such format - must be error like error_not_found or like this.

Comment: @RbMm. No, documentation is wrong here. Although you could have figured it out on your own by asking what the error code is for wrong clipboard format. There is none allocated, so there's no SetLastError call that sets it for OP's case.

Comment: i not view sense continue. i think everybody already say here all what want and we begin repeat the same. one man here give good example with `PathFileExistsW`

Comment: I've done what @MikeCAT suggested and caused another error before calling this function. Whether or not the requested clipboard format is found, the previous error persists, so `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()` does not set the error status at all. Whether that is a 'bug' or a documentation error is moot.

Answer (score 0):

the `IsClipboardFormatAvailable` call `NtUserIsClipboardFormatAvailable` in kernel.

function look like next

```
WINDOWSTATION * CheckClipboardAccess();
CLIP * FindClipFormat(WINDOWSTATION * pWinSta, UINT format, ULONG);

BOOLEAN NtUserIsClipboardFormatAvailable(_In_ UINT format)
{
    BOOLEAN fOk = FALSE;
    EnterSharedCrit();
    if (WINDOWSTATION * pWinSta = CheckClipboardAccess())
    {
        if (pWinSta == <some global data>)
        {
            if (grpdeskLogon != <thread desktop>)
            {
                fOk = (0 != FindClipFormat(pWinSta, format, 1));
            }
        }
    }
    UserSessionSwitchLeaveCrit();
    
    return fOk;
}
```

the `CheckClipboardAccess` have sign of set last error in some case - it call`NTSTATUS ReferenceWindowStation(..)` and if api fail - call

```
status = ReferenceWindowStation(..)
if (0 > status) UserSetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(status))
```

but in case thread desktop equal too `grpdeskLogon` (this is *Winlogon* desktop) visible that now eny error is set. if look for `FindClipFormat` also visible that function not set any error if format not found.

so if we got 0 (FALSE) on return - we can not know real reason - or because requested format not found in clipboard, or because we on winlogon desktop, or wrong window station, or something else.

and about how windows work.

if we request some object (or check if it exist) and it not exist - this is **error by design**. of course possible make another design. but windows designed as designed. if no requested object (or check) returned - this is error and error code must explain reason - access denied, or object not found, or sharing violation, or something else. this is common rule for **any** windows objects - files, registry keys, named events, etc.

if we try open object (or check) and can not - this is error and it must be direct or indirect (via last error) returned. windows have special statuses for such situation. for example

```
STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
STATUS_NOT_FOUND
STATUS_OBJECTID_NOT_FOUND
...
```

so in current case we simply have minor windows bug

---

> @vasek OK if this is a bug as you say, then what is the `GetLastError`
> returned from `PathFileExistsA` once you can access the path but the
> file does not exist? i.e. no error, but the file is just not there? If
> it's zero, then I don't think this answer is correct.

great example. i think that must be `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` returned from kernel, and translated to `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`. but let check

```
SetLastError(0);
PathFileExistsW(L"c:\\1234");
RtlGetLastNtStatus(); // STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
GetLastError(); // ERROR_NOT_FOUND
PathFileExistsW(L"c:\\?*"); //
RtlGetLastNtStatus(); // STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID
GetLastError(); // ERROR_INVALID_NAME
```

so again - here we not request open file. we only ask - are file exist ? like ask - are clipboard format exist ? if use logic that this is not error (if file simply not exist (and name is correct)) - the error  must be 0. but really error is `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` (`STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID`) as and must

---

here was dispute about: error or not, if the object we are asking about does not exist. This, of course, a philosophical question, but in windows there is a certain pattern for this - and yes, this is an error and exist special error codes for such a situation.

and the documentation doesn’t say that the LastError should be set on "error" case only. it must be set always if api return 0.

> If the clipboard format is not available, the return value is zero. To
> get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

by windows patters - `GetLastError` **always** must be set in case api return 0. and **never** be 0 (`NOERROR`)

and this error code must explain reason. error this is not only invalid parameter to api call or 0 pointer. object not exist usual error in windows

Comment: I think you are making an assumption of how you think the error status should work, in this case.

Comment: @RbMm OK if this is a bug as you say, then what is the `GetLastError` returned from `PathFileExistsA` once you can access the path but the file does not exist? i.e. no error, but the file is just not there? If it's zero, then I don't think this answer is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, i not make assumptions. i based on self huge experience in windows internals. and again - if we on WInlogon desktop - also will be false, but with no error set anyway

Comment: The *real reason* (if there is no error) is simply that the format isn't present. What else could Windows tell you about why you expect it to be present?

Comment: @WeatherVane - no, format can present, but if we on winlogon desktop - will be FALSE and  last error not set. i already several time say you this. and again - this is no how windows work

Comment: The *real* issue here is a boy who doesn't understand how to read documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable please be clear – *which* boy?

Comment: @vasek - thanks for `PathFileExistsA` -great example. api set last error to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (`STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`). try check it by self

Comment: OP isn't on the winlogon desktop though. That's not the problem.

Comment: @Joshua - from where code can know on which desktop it run ? if take this exe and exec on this desktop ? or need do special checks for this ? really ? exist common paterns. and this patters say set error if object not exist too.

Comment: @RbMm: Read question. OP said what he did. He copied an image into the clipboard and ran the program and wondered why GetLastError() returned 0.

Comment: This is the idiom that Windows APIs tend to follow, but for cases like this they might not care about last error because you can't really do anything about it. I mean what are you supposed to do if it fails with ERROR_INVALID_WINDOWSTATION vs ERROR_NOT_FOUND? It could also just be an oversight in the implementation.

Comment: @Joshua because was bug in implementation. api must set last error if return false. and it not do it

Comment: @Luke for this case - IsClipboardFormatAvailable we can not care abot real error reason at all. if api return false - so not Available. and even not try check last error. fut if question formal asked - here by docs api must *To get extended error information, call GetLastError.* and object not exist - this is exactly error by windows idiom

Comment: Yes, formally it's a bug with implementation and/or documentation.

Comment: @Luke - how for me - documentation is clear here - *f the clipboard format is not available, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.* - **must** be set last error if function return false. and this error **must** explain reason. if reason - no such format - must be error like error_not_found or like this. however this is very minor and not critical bug of implementation

Comment: Well, when the implementation doesn't match the documentation it's a bit of a philosophical question as to which is wrong :) but yes I tend to agree with you in this case.

Comment: @Luke That's not what the argument was about here at all. but about whether there is an error or not, if the object we are asking about does not exist. This, of course, is also a philosophical question, but in windows there is a certain pattern for this - yes, this is an error and special error codes for such a situation. and the documentation doesn’t say that the LastError should be set on "error"  only. it must be set **always** if api return 0. and this error code must explain reason. error this is nnot only invalid parameter to api call or 0 pointer. object not exist usual error

Comment: I don't care about the argument, I care about the original question which was about the implementation not matching the documentation which clearly says GetLastError can be called if API returns 0.

Comment: @Luke i agree with you. but how you can see, some peoples have another view here. they say if `GetLastError` return 0 this is mean - no error, and not available format this is no error. but from patern - if api "fail" (return false) - `GetLastError` **never** must return 0.

Comment: @Luke *"the documentation \[...\] clearly says GetLastError can be called if API returns 0"* - That's nowhere to be found in the documentation. The formatting may suggest this interpretation, but it's not spelled out. You can call `GetLastError()` to get extended error information, but there is no information on how to determine the error condition.

Comment: @IInspectable *how to determine the error condition* - here absolute clear error condition - *the return value is zero*. this is standard windows pattern, for api(s) which set last error code, instead return it directly. documented some error value on return (usually `FALSE`(0) or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`(-1) , `WAIT_FAILED`(-1) ...) and if this value returned - last error was set

Comment: *"here absolute clear error condition - **the return value is zero**"* - It is not. "No" is a valid answer to a yes/no question. Receiving a value of `FALSE` does not by itself indicate failure. It is conceivable that the function will return `FALSE` in case of error, but the documentation doesn't provide sufficient detail to determine whether a return value of `FALSE` indicates success or failure.

Comment: @IInspectable In some specific cases, the documentation is not ideal, confusing, and sometimes simply erroneous. I think you yourself know more than one such example. this is not scripture. but there is a general logic and a general pattern in windows. and according to this pattern - if this function returned false, then this is error and its code are in the last error. you are trying to dig into words to extract the desired meaning from them

Comment: *"there is a general logic and a general pattern in windows"* - I'm sure there is. But the pattern you are thinking of is for APIs that report success/failure as the function's return value. The function discussed here doesn't fall into that category. Its return value is the answer to a yes/no question. Applying the same rationale for a different category of APIs to this function isn't going to produce any useful insights.

Comment: @IInspectable yes/no here the same as success/failure. logic must be maximum simply. and must be clear when last error set and when it undefined. This is pattern. If this api return true - last error is undefined. If api return false - last error is set. So we can check last error here always, if api return false. but if set some value to last error before api call ( let be -1) and check it after api return 0, visible that last error not was set at all, despite must. It not set to 0. It unchanged, which was implementation bug.

Comment: *"yes/no here the same as success/failure"* - That's a creative interpretation that doesn't coincide with reality. It is made up, and everything that follows from there on forward is just ludicrous. Let's end it here until you're willing to have a fact-based conversation.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, this is you try do "creative interpretation" out of reality.must be an **unambiguous** criterion when an error code is set. and it is must be based on function return value, because no more here exist at all. so when this api return 0 - **must** be set last error. but it not set. all this is 100%. but you ignore this